# ExtractTextPlugin only works with webpack's --inline flag

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I'll start this off by saying I'm new to Webpack, so I apologize if this is a silly question.

From what my understanding is the --inline flag is used with webpack-dev-server for hot loading.

However, when using the ExtractTextPlugin and doing:

```
    webpack webpack.config.js
```

I get an output with a lot of warnings and some errors:

```
    Hash: af8bbcc48570fd43cda4
    Version: webpack 1.13.1
    Time: 9383ms
            Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
        bundle.js   2.96 MB       0  [emitted]  main
../css/styles.css  82 bytes       0  [emitted]  main
    bundle.js.map   3.54 MB       0  [emitted]  main
../css/styles.css.map  94 bytes       0  [emitted]  main

    [0] multi main 40 bytes {0} [built]
    [1] ./www/assets/js/entry.js 2 kB {0} [built]
    [8] ./webpack.config.js 1.24 kB {0} [built]
    + 524 hidden modules
    WARNING in ./~/fsevents/fsevents.js
    Critical dependencies:
    11:13-71 the request of a dependency is an expression
     @ ./~/fsevents/fsevents.js 11:13-71


    WARNING in ./~/fsevents/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/package.json
    Module parse failed: /Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/nw-pre-gyp/package.json Unexpected token (2:6)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:6)
        at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:923:13)
        at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1490:8)
        at Parser.pp.semicolon (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1469:73)
        at Parser.pp.parseExpressionStatement (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1994:8)
        at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1772:188)
        at Parser.pp.parseBlock (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2009:21)
        at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1753:19)
        at Parser.pp.parseTopLevel (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1666:21)
        at Parser.parse (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1632:17)
        at Object.parse (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:885:44)
        at Parser.parse (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
        at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
        at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
        at nextLoader (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
        at /Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
        at Storage.provide (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:52:20)
        at CachedInputFileSystem.readFile (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:140:24)
        at DependenciesBlock.onLoadPitchDone (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:255:7)
        at DependenciesBlock.loadPitch (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:182:27)
        at DependenciesBlock.doBuild (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:241:4)
        at DependenciesBlock.build (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:84:14)
        at Compilation.buildModule (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:126:9)
        at /Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:309:10
        at /Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:58:13
        at NormalModuleFactory.applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:75:69)
        at onDoneResolving (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:38:11)
        at onDoneResolving (/Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:121:6)
        at /Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:116:7
        at /Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:726:13
        at /Users/mt24/Documents/demo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
     @ ./~/fsevents/~/node-pre-gyp/lib ^\.\/.*$
```

Also, notice the file size for bundle.js is **2.96 MB** versus when I do :

```
    webpack --inline webpack.config.js
```

(It's not using webpack-dev-server because I don't want hot-reloading for the purpose of this question)

My output is :

```
    Hash: 7543a8fc94cb447e7082
    Version: webpack 1.13.1
    Time: 11073ms
                    Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                bundle.js    278 kB       0  [emitted]  main
        ../css/styles.css  82 bytes       0  [emitted]  main
            bundle.js.map    351 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    ../css/styles.css.map  94 bytes       0  [emitted]  main

       [0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built]
       [1] ./www/assets/js/entry.js 2 kB {0} [built]
        + 6 hidden modules
    Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
            + 2 hidden modules
```

Now notice the file size is at **278 kB** and there are no more warnings / errors.

My webpack.config.js looks like:

```
    var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
    var path = require('path');

    var nodeModulesPath = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules');

    module.exports = {
        entry : [path.join(__dirname, '/www/assets/js/entry')],
        output: {
            filename: 'bundle.js',
            path: path.join(__dirname, '/www/dist/assets/js')
        },
        module: {   
            loaders: [
                { 
                    test:   /\.css$/,
                    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
                },
                {
                    test: /\.es6\.js$/,
                    exclude: nodeModulesPath,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query : {
                        presets : ['es2015']
                    }
                }, 
                { 
                    test:   /\.json$/,
                    loader: 'json-loader',
                    exclude: nodeModulesPath,
                },
            ],
        },
        plugins : [
             new ExtractTextPlugin(path.join('..','css', 'styles.css'))
        ],  
        resolveLoaded : {
            root : nodeModulesPath
        },
        resolve: {
           extensions: ['', '.js', '.es6', '.json', '']
        },  
        node: {
            console: 'empty',
            fs: 'empty',
            net: 'empty',
            tls: 'empty'
        }, 
        devtool : 'source-map'
    };
```

My questions are:

1. Should I always be using the --inline flag? Is this standard practice?
2. Why does the file size of bundle.js increase soo much when the --inline is removed?
3. Does using --inline cause any strange behavior once this gets bundled for a production build?